# Возможно ли удалить ветку из репозитория полностью?

Tags: git, gitlab

Такая ситуация: случайно залил на одну из веток репозитория здоровый бинарник. Когда это понял удалил ветку с бинарником из этого репозитория, но, тем не менее на размер репозитория это не повлияло. Как можно очистить репозиторий от этой ненужной информации?

Comment: `на размер репозитория это не повлияло` что подразумеваете под этим?

Comment: а эта ветка была вмержена куда-нибудь?

Comment: @InDevX Это означает, что файл остался в репозитории (так работает гит).

Comment: @Grundy нет, не мержилась ни с чем

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255802/after-deleting-a-binary-file-from-git-history-why-is-my-repository-still-large

Comment: @Эникейщик на сколько хватает моего английского, я понял, что это (первый ответ) способ для удаления файлов из репозитория. А как насчет удаления целой ветки